# Is it possible to insert a row using the INSERT function on a queried table?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO (
    SELECT student_info.Student_Name,scores.Final
    FROM student_info 
    INNER JOIN scores ON scores.Student_id=student_info.Student_id 
        AND scores.Subject_id=1)
(Student_Name,Final) VALUES("a",1)
```

Something like this.....What i want to achieve is that i want to add a new row to the queried result which will display the average of the columns above it.

Comment: Where are you calculating an average?

Comment: You can't insert into multiple tables in a single operation.

Comment: If that's not what you're trying to do, I can't figure out what this question is asking.

Comment: Instead of the 1 in the values, I wanted to insert the average.....I am yet to figure that part out

Comment: `INSERT` is for adding a row to a table. Which table do you want to insert into?

Comment: It's not a table that I wish to insert into but the queried result

Comment: What does it mean to insert into results? If you want to add additional rows to a result, use `UNION` to combine two queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` to combine the results of two queries into a single result:

```
SELECT student_info.Student_Name,scores.Final
FROM student_info 
INNER JOIN scores ON scores.Student_id=student_info.Student_id 
    AND scores.Subject_id=1

UNION

SELECT "a", AVG(scores.Final)
FROM student_info 
INNER JOIN scores ON scores.Student_id=student_info.Student_id 
    AND scores.Subject_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need  an insert select  you could use this way

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name  (Student_Name,Final)
SELECT student_info.Student_Name,scores.Final
FROM student_info 
INNER JOIN scores ON scores.Student_id=student_info.Student_id 
AND scores.Subject_id=1
```

and eventually if need a added  row you can add an union clause with the literal value to your select

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name   (Student_Name,Final)
SELECT student_info.Student_Name,scores.Final
FROM student_info 
INNER JOIN scores ON scores.Student_id=student_info.Student_id 
AND scores.Subject_id=1
union all  
select "a", 1
from dual;
```

Comment: You need a table name after `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: @scaisEdge In my case, I wish to insert row into a queried result.......is it possible to name the queried result??

Comment: [Student_Name,Final]
[a,   25]          
[b,   58]              
[c,   67]            
[d,   46]          


After my query this is my result(^)  and i wish to add a row in this saying

Average   49